# Как загрузить изображение с админки django в шаблон

Tags: python, django, django-admin

**Задача загрузить изображение с админки Django2 в шаблон**

*Структура проекта*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class Img(models.Model):
    img_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    img = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.img_title
```

*urls.py*(в приложение)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.upload_file, name="index")
]
```

*admin.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
admin.site.register(Img)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import *

def upload_file(request):
    objects = Img.objects.all()
    return render(request, "app1/index.html", context={'cnt': objects})
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <ul>
    {% for elem in cnt %}
    <h2>{{elem.img_title}}</h2>
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ elem.img.url }}"alt="Изображение не загрузилось" />
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}

  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**Результат**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто `{{ elem.img.url }}`, без приставки `{{ MEDIA_URL }}`.

Comment: Тотже самый результат, хотя путь генерируется правильный `/media/images/wallpapers-mountains-2.jpg`

Comment: Это значит, что у вас не настроено [обслуживание статики](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).

Comment: Да и в правду, все так спасибо помогло, как по мне довольно запутанная система...